# What russian search engine or social network service is this?

Tags: search-engines

[image: What search engine is this?]

The above logo of a search engine is supposedly the top in russia. I would like to know more about the company so I can do SEO for it.

When I google for "Russia top search engine" I only get Yandex. Does anyone know what search engine is it?

PS: I am chinese.

Comment: Do you know that you can search on Google Image using an url? Just paste the link of your image and Google will find `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odnoklassniki.ru` ;)

Comment: I got the image from a PDF. I tried the mobile version of google goggles on my iphone, scanning it with camera but didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Odnoklassniki.ru** is a social network service for classmates and old friends. It's popular in Russia and former Soviet Republics.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odnoklassniki.ru).

Answer (score 0):

"Odnoklassniki" has more than 200 million registered users and 45 million daily unique visitors. Users have to be at least seven years old to create an account. This is a really popular social network in Russia after "VKontakte".